# Access Migrations via console in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails . This might be a very foolish question.

I have created a migration using

```
rails generate migration Kapol name:string position:integer

rake db:migrate
```

Then using phpmyadmin i copied the database already present
I then opened up rails console

My question is can i use the method Kapol.find(1)??
because when i tried it using singular or plural it says

```
unitialized constant:Kapol
```

I know that there has to be a method but where to specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must generate a **model** in case to create a table for it, because the **migration** is usually used to modify existing tables.

It might be confusing that the model generator also creates migration file in your migrations folder. The only difference is that the *model generator* also generates initial code to create table, on the other hand, the *migration generator* creates only migration file without initial code.

```
rails generate model Kapol name:string position:integer
```

More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-model

Answer (score 1):

If you're very new to Ruby on Rails, probably the best thing for you to do is create a *scaffold*, which gives you your migration file, your model file, your controller file, and various view files, test files, etc. etc., which all work well together.  Then you can play with these and build up from there.

```
rails generate scaffold Kapol name:string position:integer
```

If you're happy with the migration that was automatically generated, then `rake db:migrate` and you're all set.

As Andrew says below, you can also just generate any of those files one at a time by replacing 'scaffold' with 'model', etc.

Your `Kapol.find(1)` is correct.